# Silverlight and SQLDataSource

Tags: silverlight, sqldatasource

Is it not possible to use a SQLDataSource in an aspx page inside a Silverlight application?

Comment: a more descriptive title and extra tags would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

No. But take a look at **[RIA Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/03/19/what-is-net-ria-services.aspx)**. It provides similar functionality...

- [Brad Abrams : What is .NET RIA Services?](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/03/19/what-is-net-ria-services.aspx)
- [Nikhil Kothari's Weblog : .NET RIA Services: From Vision to Architecture](http://www.nikhilk.net/NET-RIA-Services-Vision-Architecture.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

silverlight is client side you cannot use a sqldatasource

Essentially the features offered by Silverlight are just a subset of the full .NET framework.

If you need data in your Silverlight application you will have to call a Web Service that will hand you the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

Go for ADO .net Data Services

http://www.devx.com/MSDN/Article/40735/1763/page/1

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use SQLDataSource, I'll have to refer you back to your earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716875/how-do-i-integrate-a-silverlight-front-end-and-a-database-back-end) about the same subject.